# How to edit element in table with selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to edit value of element that placed it the table on 
[this page](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable).
I'm using this code:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable");

    WebElement firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gwt-debug-contentPanel\"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/div"));

    firstName.click();
    firstName.clear();
    firstName.sendKeys("test");
```

It says:
"Element must be user-editable in order to clear it."
How i can edit this element?
Also i have troubles with "Category" field on this page. I'm trying to select each of them successively. Doing this with:

```
WebElement category = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gwt-debug-contentPanel\"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[4]/div/select"));

        category.sendKeys("Businesses");
        category.sendKeys("Friends");
        category.sendKeys("Coworkers");
        category.sendKeys("Businesses");
        category.sendKeys("Family");
```

I tried to make        `category.sendKeys("");` once and it works well.
But throws this: "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" when i get a lot. How i can change this elements one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda a strange one. The DOM keeps changing which makes it harder to see what's going on so that you can do the right thing to make it work. You have to click one element which changes the DOM and inserts an INPUT which is what you need to `.sendKeys()` to. I have tested the code below and it works.

I like to create functions for things like this so that they are reusable. This function changes the first name. `rowIndex` is the row of the table you want to change and `firstName` is the desired first name. You have to wait for the table to finish loading because it loads dynamically after the page is loaded.

```
public static void setFirstName(int rowIndex, String firstName)
{
    WebElement firstNameElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("tr[__gwt_row='" + rowIndex + "'] > td > div")))
            .get(1);
    firstNameElement.click();
    firstNameElement.findElement(By.tagName("input")).sendKeys(firstName + "\n");
}
```

To change the first name of the first row to "FirstName" you would call it like,

```
setFirstName(0, "FirstName");
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Can you help me with changing elements in "Category" field?

Comment: Please also tell me how css selector will be look like when i need to change last name if you can

Comment: If you found this answer useful, please upvote it. If it answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Now that you have an example, you should take some time to examine it and figure out how it works so you can adapt it to the other columns. If you try and can't figure it out, post what you have tried in a new question and I or others will try to help you.